# How do I utilize Visual C++'s code model outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I would like to build a tool that takes a set of C/C++ headers and macro definitions and outputs a list of visible types, functions, variables, and macros, preferably with full type information. At first, I thought about using the Clang APIs, but I primarily wanted to use this tool on the Windows SDK headers and I would probably need to pre-process them to get Clang to parse them correctly. The C++ parser in Visual Studio already extracts the information I need, so it would be nice if I could just use that.

Is it possible to do something like that without writing a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: I believe that Clang has flags you can use to get it to accept the non-standard conforming code in Microsoft headers. You could try that.

Comment: do coati.io, doxygraph, and doxygen sort of work?

Comment: @DeepCoder You're right. It seems Clang 3.9.1 can parse the Windows SDK headers just fine, even without the `-fms-extensions` flag. I guess I'll just go ahead and use `libclang`, then.